# Polygon mainnet has two official ERC20 Link token contract. Which one DEXs use when on polygon mainnet

Tags: erc-20, polygon, bridge

I was going through the top erc20 token by marketcap on polygonscan. There I have found these two LINK tokens:
`https://polygonscan.com/token/0x53e0bca35ec356bd5dddfebbd1fc0fd03fabad39` ~ from polygon team.

`https://polygonscan.com/token/0xb0897686c545045afc77cf20ec7a532e3120e0f1` ~ from chainlink team.

Which one is real? and which one DEXs use to swap tokens when they use polygon mainnet?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

They are both real tokens.

- `0x53e0bca35ec356bd5dddfebbd1fc0fd03fabad39`
  This is the token bridged from Ethereum. It's a normal ERC20 and it has the best liquidity on dexes, so it's the one you generally buy/sell or whatever.
- `0xb0897686c545045afc77cf20ec7a532e3120e0f1`
  This is the token used to pay for Chainlink services. Since these services need a ERC677 token (an extension of ERC20), you can't use the previous one. So this is a ERC677 "wrapped" version of the first.

You can convert between the two using a contract called PegSwap at this address: [0xAA1DC356dc4B18f30C347798FD5379F3D77ABC5b](https://polygonscan.com/address/0xAA1DC356dc4B18f30C347798FD5379F3D77ABC5b#code).

Source: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/#polygon-matic